# Reuse an Object URI in .NET RemotingServices

Tags: c#, .net, uri, appdomain, remoting

If I create an object and marshal it across AppDomains using RemotingServices, like so:

```
Object obj = new Object();
RemotingServices.Marshal(obj, null, null);
```

Is there a way to later marshal a new object using the same URI? I imagine I would have to remove the first object, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to disconnect the first object before you can marshal a new object using the same URI by calling:

```
RemotingServices.Disconnect(obj);
```

See [RemotingServices.Disconnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.disconnect(v=vs.110).aspx)